# iterm2 command history

Tags: iterm, zsh

I like the iterm2 command history which can be triggered by `command+shift+;`.  However, I observation is it does not have the whole history that I can get from the `history` command.  For example, I shutdown my mac today, and power it on tomorrow.  I lost the today's command history.  Is there way achieving this?

I'm using zsh, oh-my-zsh by the way.

Comment: Are you exiting iTerm cleanly and completely before rebooting or do you shutdown with a window(s) still open?

Comment: No, but it does not explain this `history` command gives way too many commands than the iterm history, right?

Comment: `history` is written upon exit of the current *session* where as iTerm saves on *program termination*.   Test to see if it saves your commands by exiting cleanly and again by just shutting down/restarting

Comment: You mean I need to use `exit` to explicitly quit a session?

Comment: Ok.  I used `exit` to quit the session. I can see the command history.  However, if I use `Command + Q` to quit iterm2, and launch it again.  I lose everything.

Comment: `exit` cleanly terminates the program saving your history whereas  `Cmd-Q` appears to be simply terminating the app.  Use `exit` to ensure your history is saved.  Also, you do have shell integration installed?

Comment: I used `exit` to exit all of my sessions (all tabs).  Then I used `Cmd+Q` to quit iterm2.  I started it again, and I did not see any of my history.  Yes, shell integration installed.

Comment: The `history` command is the history being retained by the shell you are running.  Expecting `iterm` to maintain a history depends on it screen-scraping the session, and then being able to save it out to a file.  Use the shell history.

Comment: @MarcWilson  You mean there's no way for iterm remembering all commands?

Comment: @Bomin I wouldn't know.  The `history` command in the shell provides the complete list of commands the shell has executed.  If what `iterm` provides is less than complete, then you know what to use.

Comment: Ok.  The reason I like iterm is they have shortcut key and UI , and it helps me to filter.  Anyway, thanks for the information.